# use of "so far" in a negative sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there anything inappropriate in using “so far” (with the meaning “till now”) in a negative sentence? 
Eg: I have not come across such a thing so far in my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly valid.

- You invited me into this stupid haunted house, but I haven't seen a single ghost so far.
- I said I'd raise your salary when you started working harder, but so far I haven't noticed a difference.
- I've never been to Ireland so far, but I am going next September.